# Asus Maximus IV CPU instant temperature reading 63+?

Tags: cpu, temperature

When I cold boot and check the CPU temperature in the BIOS it instantly says 63+ if I reset the CMOS and cold boot up again it will say 30-40+ but then when I restart again it will instantly say 63+ anyone any idea what is going on?

Processor is i7 2600k

Answer (score 0):

63°C is a very good temperature for a computer's innards.

The CMOS probably powers the thermometer as well so when you reset it the thermometer in the computer has to restart which takes a while but when you don't twiddle with the CMOS it'll stay stable.

Comment: Actually 63C is quite high for idle on that CPU. i7s run hot, sure, but 63C is too high to be considered "normal".

Comment: Yeah I'm sure its an incorrect reading, 63+ on cold boot? I don't understand.

Comment: @Question Cold boot? You said restart above.